# How to calculate $ \mathbb{E}\left[X|W=0\right] $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $ X\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right) $ and define $$ W=\begin{cases}
0 & X<0\\
X & X\geq0
\end{cases} =  X\boldsymbol{1}_{X\geq0} $$

How can I calculate $ \mathbb{E}\left[X|W\right]$ ?

Here's what I have tried so far:

I want to identify this random variable for any value $ w $ such that $W=w$. So I first noticed that

And now all I have to do is to calculate $ \mathbb{E}\left[X|W=0\right] $.
Since $W$ is neither a continuous or a discrete time variable, Im not sure how to express the conditioned density. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$W=0$ iff $X \leq 0$. So $E(X|W=0)=E(X|X\leq 0)$. By symmetry of $N(0,1)$ we have $E(X|X>0)=E(-X|X <0)$. Also $E|X|=E(XI_{X>0})+E(XI_{X<0})$.  Combine these to get $E(X|W=0)=\frac 1 2 E|X|$ and  $E|X|=\sqrt {\frac 2 {\pi}}$

Comment: Im not sure Im familier with the definition of $ \mathbb{E}\left[X|X\leq0\right]$. The definition I know, is $ \mathbb{E}\left[X|W=w\right]=\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|W=w}\left(x\right)dx $. What does it mean to condition on something that is not a random variable?

Comment: @FreeZe See Çonditional expectation on an event' in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation

Comment: . . . . and then we have the problem of evaluating $\operatorname E\left|X\right|. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Computation of $E|X|$ is quite trivial.  OP should do some work. We should not post answers in a way the askers can cut and paste the solution into their homework.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy : Computation of $\operatorname E(X)$ is a quick first-year calculus exercise, and is also one that many who encounter this problem don't know how to do.